# Vuejs into kubernetes cluster and nginx ingress returns 404 when refreshed

Tags: vue.js, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to run a Vue.js frontend service into nginx-ingress enabled kubernetes cluster. The application has 4 routes, /, /foo/, /bar and /about. If I access the application and refresh the page in any route besides /, I get a 404 error from nginx ingress.

I'm using kubernetes version v1.18.2 (both client and server). The cluster was created by the kind (kubernetes in docker program) and I setup the ingress following their documentation at https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/ingress/#ingress-nginx. The example application I'm using is this one: https://github.com/ovitor/foo

Here are the deployments, services and ingress used.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: foo
  name: foo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: vcml10/foo:latest
        name: foo
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: foo
  name: foo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: foo
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: foo
              servicePort: 80
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because you have path only for `/`.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: foo
              servicePort: 80
```

---

If you want to make it work for `/ /foo/ /bar and /about` you would have to add additional paths.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: foo-ingress
    spec:
      rules:
        - http:
            paths:
              - path: /
                backend:
                  serviceName: foo
                  servicePort: 80
              - path: /foo
                backend:
                  serviceName: foo
                  servicePort: 80
              - path: /bar
                backend:
                  serviceName: foo
                  servicePort: 80
              - path: /about
                backend:
                  serviceName: foo
                  servicePort: 80
```

---

**OR**

---

Use [regex](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/) as mentioned in the nginx ingress documentation

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo/.*
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

---

Additionally you can take a look at [rewrite annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/).

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, your answer was correct if I didn't have any problem with the foo docker image. The problem relies on nginx configuration of the docker image. The default nginx docker image doesn't have the `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` configuration. This options is necessary to vuejs and other frontend frameworks like angular works as excpected. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56213079/404-error-on-page-refresh-with-angular-7-nginx-and-docker